# Yogscast complete pack server files

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I want to play the Yogscast complete modpack for Minecraft with a friend, but I want my own server (so I can be opped). Does anyone know where I can get the server files for download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the Yogscast Complete pack on the AT Launcher. In the GUI, if you use "Create Server", it enables you to open a dedicated server. There is no dedicated download, you just enable and start it through the ATLauncher GUI.